# How to compute the mean-square in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to compute the square of mean-square for each element of `l`

```
  l=[0.02817088, -0.74100320, -0.54062120, -0.24612808,  0.06945337, -0.58415690, -0.51238549, 
 -0.07862326, -0.42417337, -0.33482340, -0.21339753, -0.03890844, -0.59325371,  0.28154593, 
   -0.32133359,-0.13534792,  0.14060645,  0.32204972,  0.44438052, -0.21750973,-0.59107599, 
 -0.60809913]'

 k= -0.2224834

 sum(l-k)^2/22
```

I am not sure if `sum(l-k)^2/22` is the sum of each `(l[j]-k)` for j=1,2,...,22?

ans = 2.4223e-14

Comment: you can type `l-k` in the command line and discover it yourself :)

Comment: Are you sure that you use MATLAB? What you have posted seems a mismatch between MATLAB syntax on one hand, and Python syntax on the other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you need might be

```
>> mean((l-k).^2)
ans =  0.10945
```

**Data** (You need `...` for line continuation if you have data in different lines for `l`)

```
l=[0.02817088, -0.74100320, -0.54062120, -0.24612808,  0.06945337, -0.58415690, -0.51238549, ...
 -0.07862326, -0.42417337, -0.33482340, -0.21339753, -0.03890844, -0.59325371,  0.28154593, ...
   -0.32133359,-0.13534792,  0.14060645,  0.32204972,  0.44438052, -0.21750973,-0.59107599, ...
 -0.60809913]'

k= -0.2224834
```